# Python PUT requests, send int instead of string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I need to use a PUT request from python's library requests. The XML has to be String, but I need to send the value  as an Int.

```
import requests
bodyXML = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><parameters><value>6</value></parameters>"""
bodyHeader = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
p = requests.put('http://test.pt:1891/cash', data=bodyXML, headers=bodyHeader)
```

The answer is:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?><reply-text>Value must be numeric.</reply-text>
```

That's an answer from the program, so I can reach the target and get the response.

If I change 6 to """ + 6 + """, I receive an error in Python

```
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

How can I camuflate the integer as String?

Comment: You will *always* send that data as a string. If that’s not how the server expects the value to be provided, you will have to talk to that service provider to ask them how to format your data so that it properly accepts the value.

Comment: It could be they require a separate node or attribute denoting the type of the value. You need to ask your provider what is the proper way to set the type.

Comment: So, there's no turn around. How can I accept your comment as the right answer @poke?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As stubborn as a programmer can be, I found a way to send values as they are using lxml to build the XML and adding a string "post_xml=" before the XML to send, works just fine:

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element("parameters")
child = etree.SubElement(root, "value")
child.text = str(str(6))

xml = str('post_xml=') + etree.tostring(root, encoding='unicode', method='xml')
p = requests.request("PUT", 'http://test.pt:1891/cash', data=xml)

print(p.text)
```

The value 6 is accepted as an integer by the server.

Comment: There is nothing new about this solution that hasn’t been already said. `str(str(6))` is the same as `'6'` and the resulting XML is the same that you already had in your question. The difference is the `post_xml=` prefix that comes in front of the body, which is obviously what makes the server accept the request. As I said in my answer, this is specific to the service provider and you should have asked them in the first place how to format the data.

Comment: Well, this answer works, solves my problem, that's what the "accept this answer" looks for right? And there are 2 new things in this solution. The lxml and the string "post_xml=". str(6) isn't the same as 6, I get error. 
Your answer was "[...]you should talk to the service provider to ask them how to properly format the data[...]", it's a suggestion and I accepted that answer when there was no solution. Now that there is one, I showed it and accepted it as right answer, you don't have to down vote it.

Answer (score 1):

When you send data as part of the HTTP request body, that data will always be sent as a string (technically, it's just bytes that happen to encode a string). Furthermore XML is a text based format so that also *has* to be a string.

If the server does not accept the data you send, then you should talk to the service provider to ask them how to properly format the data in order for the server to accept it.

It is likely that the XML structure requires a different tag for number formats or even requires a special attribute to specify the type.

Since that is specific to your service, we won't be able to answer this for you though.

Answer (score -2):

Easy assuming you are putting the +6+ in the place of the 
`bodyXML = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><parameters><value>6</value></parameters>"""` 6 in value. The issue is that the string line notation “””, is terminating before 6. In order to fix this just `import requests
bodyXML = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><parameters><value>”””+”6”+”””</value></parameters>"""` convert the int to a string via quotations or convert by encapsulating the 6 in string() like string(6).

Comment: You're effectively generating the same string as OP. OP's problem is more likely related to server input requirements (i.e. number format)

Comment: My solution asks the op to convert the int to a string, server input aka standardized xml needs string input, using int format doesn’t allow for interpretation across different systems. My solution used the same number as op for ease but I should clarify substitute the six for x=someint and convert to string in order to pass appropriately. If the standard format for values has bounds than create an enum that holds the potential values and convert to string if you use intenum. Otherwise i don’t see how my answer doesn’t identify the issue.

Comment: Using the "" or the string() will always turn the number 6 into string, and the program will not accept it.

Comment: Oh I’m stupid I didn’t see the server response about the numeric. Yeah my answer won’t fix that. Sorry about that